# (Error 2) No such file or directory in Python 3

Tags: python, io, python-3.2

I'm trying to display text from a file but am getting the mentioned error. I've tried changing the default directory using `os.chdir()`. I'm also getting the error even if I save the text file in the default directory. I'm using version 3.2.

Code:

```
from sys import argv
import os

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(filename, "is the filename.")
print("Here is the text.", txt.read())

filename_again = input("Filename again pls.")
txt_again = open(filename_again)
print("Test again.", txt_again.read())
```

Error Report:

```
PS C:\Python32\Stuff\Programs> python Sample1.py fubar1.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sample1.py", line 6, in <module>
    txt = open(filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fubar1.txt'
PS C:\Python32\Stuff\Programs>
```

Comment: maybe errors in the given filename.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you put `txt.close()` before opening the file a second time?

Comment: Those double slashes have me concerned.  Is something strange going on with escape characters?

Comment: @AvinashRaj- I considered that. Tried changing the filename but am still getting the error.

Comment: @Kevin- Yes, still getting the error.

Comment: @Lattyware- I tried doing that, still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the code and it worked for me.  Tried to enter this as a comment, but don't have the points.

Tested on a *Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 using python 3.4.2*

May I suggest it may have been a typo when entering the original filename?  I tried different file names and it worked successfully.  If this is not the case then debugging time.

**Note Error Line**
The error is encountered in the first open statement so it is possible that the arguments text needs to be trimmed.

**Debugging Idea**
Noticed you are in windows.  Try using a `print()` command on line 5 to examine the contents of the filename variable.  You may have spaces before or after the filename which are then causing the open statement to fail.